# How to get a client ID for new Google project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my Google Cloud Platform dashboard, I have created a new project.

https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=my-new-project

Where do I go to get my Client ID and secret for my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the platform dashboard console, there is a menu icon in the upper left corner of the screen. Click that icon, then navigate through the following series of menus.

menu icon > APIs & Services > Credentials > Create Credentials > OAuth client ID